# SQL Server data encryption

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Practice for Database Encryption in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207819/best-practice-for-database-encryption-in-sql-server-2005)

All the work against our database done via stored procedures.
The problem is that some columns contain VERY sensitive data, so we have encrypt them.
My question is about best practices in this area and a couple of words about performance overhead.

Thanks in advance.
Ilan.

Comment: Note that there are 2 ways to encrypt here (as an approach).1)The connection to the database is encrypted but the data in the database are not.2)The data itself stored in the database are encrypted.May be depending on your requirements you could get away with option 1 which is just configuration

Comment: @user384706 we consider encrypt both, the connection and the data inside the database. Encryption of the connection only - not quite good for us, because database might be stolen.

Answer (score 1):

This is the article given to me from our company DB:

[SQL Server Encryption](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2005/11/24/sql-server-2005-data-encryption.aspx)

Comment: lol, it's also a previous answer on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207819/best-practice-for-database-encryption-in-sql-server-2005 -- The accepted answer on this page has a very good point about doing the encryption on the application side

Comment: Thank you, I'll reed this article.

Comment: @Ilan -- haha, no problem, I'm just linking articles given to me from various sources

Comment: The main problem is that there are a tons of articles, but we have not time to learn all of the possible approaches :) We need some very concrete checklist of things to do..

Comment: @ Skyrim:Just linking to something is not a good answer.You should elaborate more in order for your answer to be helpful

Comment: @user384706 -- thnx for the feddback.  I understand; I just didn't want to take credit for somebody's work by rehashing what looked to be like a more complete solution...I'll be more careful in the future.